# SSIS: Getting conflict error while importing data from source to multiple destination tables in SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I am trying to import data from source table to multiple destination tables in my SSIS package.

[image: SSIS package snippet]

If I remove `multicast` then how to link 2 destination tables.

[image: After removing multicast]

While doing it, I am getting following error:

> > [AEParam [49]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is
> > available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"
> > Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The statement has been
> > terminated.". An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL
> > Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The
> > INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
> > "FK__AE__event__32E0915F". The conflict occurred in database "xx",
> > table "dbo.AEvent", column 'eID'.".
>
> [AEParam[49]] Error: SSIS Error Code
> DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "AEParam.Inputs[OLE DB
> Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and
> the error row disposition on "AEParam.Inputs[OLE DB Destination
> Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified
> object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted
> before this with more information about the failure.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The
> ProcessInput method on component "AEParam" (49) failed with error code
> 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (62). The
> identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method.
> The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and
> will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error
> messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>
> [A Event [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2p4h.png)] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB
> error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is
> available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"
> Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint
> 'PK_A_EVENT'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AEvent'. The
> duplicate key value is (194).".
>
> [A Event [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2p4h.png)] Error: SSIS Error Code
> DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "A Event.Inputs[OLE DB
> Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and
> the error row disposition on "A Event.Inputs[OLE DB Destination
> Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified
> object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted
> before this with more information about the failure.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The
> ProcessInput method on component "A Event" (2) failed with error code
> 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (15). The
> identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method.
> The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and
> will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error
> messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

This is how I created Source tables. The destination tables also exactly the same like source tables.

```
    CREATE TABLE AEvent (
    eID int NOT NULL,   
    startTime datetime NOT NULL,
    endTime datetime NULL,  
    CONSTRAINT PK_A_EVENT PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (eID)
);
    
CREATE TABLE AEParam (
    eID int NOT NULL REFERENCES AEvent(eID),
    name nvarchar (446) NOT NULL,
    value nvarchar (2048) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_A_E_PARAM PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (eID, name)
);
```

This is the View I used to get the data from the source tables.

```
CREATE view [dbo].[vw_Test]
AS
SELECT  AE.[eventID]  
      ,AE.[startTime]
      ,AE.[endTime]    
      ,AEP.[name]
      ,AEP.[value]
  FROM [dbo].[AEvent] AE
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[AEParam] AEP
  ON AE.eID=AEP.eID
  
GO
```

I am using multicast in my SSIS package to import the data into 2 different tables in the destination.

Answer (score 0):

As you are having parent child relationship, you need to INSERT parent followed by child. So, you should not do MULTICAST into parent, child tables.

Follow below steps:

1. First insert into AEvent
2. Later insert into AEParam

**UPDATE**

Example diagram below, where one data flow task is followed by another in the control flow.

[image: Data flow tasks sequence]

Comment: Hi Venkataraman, Could you explain me in more details. If you see the View, I am joining 2 tables and getting the data. So while inserting it in destination, I need to insert the data in 2 different tables. I am doing mapping  from View to these destination tables.

Comment: yes. those different destination tables have got parent-child relationship between them. So, you need to insert them in order: parent followed by child.

Comment: If I don't use multicast then how can I link these 2 destination tables one after another.

Comment: If I remove the `multicast`. How to connect 2 destination tables.

Comment: Have two data flow tasks, one by one sequentially. Insert parent followed by Insert child

Comment: Can you please show me some diagram? That will help me to follow the instructions. Thanks

Comment: @RjLearn, updated my answer. please check

Comment: That means I need to draw 2 control flows. One for parents data flow and another one for child. Am I right? If I need to draw inside one control flow then I need 2 sources which are the same in both parent and child case as I am using View. The only changes would be the destination tables.

Comment: Yes. you need two Data flow tasks in the control flow. One for parent, one for child. For both data flow tasks, source is same view. But, destination will be different.